# VBS Logon Script

Tags: vbscript, logon-scripts, netlogon

Could someone please provide some assistance with VBS scripting?

Here is what I have modified so far;

```
Const GROUP1 = "cn=GROUP1"
Const GROUP2 = "cn=GROUP2"
Const GROUP3 = "cn=GROUP3"

Set wshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

Set ObjectUser = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set CurrentUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & ObjectUser.UserName)
strGroups = LCase(Join(CurrentUser.MemberOf))

If InStr(strGroups, LCase("GROUP1")) Then   
  wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "L:", "\\servername\\volume1\"
End If

If InStr(strGroups, LCase("GROUP2")) Then
  wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "M:", "\\servername\volume2\"
End If

If InStr(strGroups, LCase("GROUP3")) Then
  wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "N:", "\\servername\volume3\"
End If
```

I am unsure of how best and easiest way to retreive LDAP string? I also keep getting an error on `Set CurrentUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & ObjectUser.UserName)`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: We need a bit more detail.  What LDAP string are you trying to retreive?  What error are you receiving?

Comment: Also note that this won't work right with nested group membership. You would need to traverse through the groups.

Answer (score 6):

It would be much easier if you used Group Policy Preferences to map the drives and did item-level targeting to filter drive maps by group. This is the preferred way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there have been a hundred & one solutions to mapping drives based on group membership.  You can find mine [here](http://tiki.gmartin.org/tiki-view_blog_post.php?postId=125).  It uses vbscript for some of this and cmd shell for others.  Perhaps you don't need to reinvent the wheel.